# Why Author Information isn't showing for all pages in google search result?

Tags: google-search, google-plus, rich-snippets, author, structured-data

[image: Google Search Result for my blog]

As you can see on the image, the author information is being shown only for one page, not others, why not all pages are showing the author information? Do I need to do anything additionally to get it done?

Following is the result of structured data tool preview:
[image: rich snippet tool format]

Now see what really happening on actual google search result(search with the title "How To Work With Codeigniter Caching In PHP" and mine is the 9th result on first page):
[image: real search result format]

So, what about this? Why are they different?

Comment: On social bar add a Google Plus, this helps sometimes if Google isn't playing ball... since in the header you have auther but you also have Linked author profile: http://codesamplez.com/author/admin so i think its using that rather

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will only list one Author per a site on one page of results. Since you are doing the search query "site: your domain" you are pulling up results of your domain and only 1 authorship will be listed in the serps. Your pages are working as intended.

**How to Test**

There is 2 really good methods of testing your urls to see if the rich snippets are working, one is using the Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) and as I've tested I can tell you that the authorship is being read. Another method is to search Google for the URL you want to test so in this example I used yourdomain and url of contact into the search and this was displayed:

[Google Author Working http://www.bybe.net/downloads/author-working-011.jpg](http://www.bybe.net/downloads/author-working-011.jpg)

Ensure you always test you pages without the site:// attribute as Google filters certain things out. You want to find your page as REAL visitors would, So copy the url or even the title of the page in full in future.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your information. However, I still did get different result. Check my updated description with two more results. Hope its make sense. Please let me know what is happening here. Thanks.