# Google authorship verification fails because Google does not recognize my full four part name

Tags: google-search-console, rich-snippets, author

In the email verification section, I see a message as the image below:

[image]

I am not sure, why it is detecting my name as 'ali rana' instead of "Md Ali Ahsan Rana". Can you please suggest how to get rid of this issue please?

I am still facing issue on showing rich snippet preview of my blog posts as I mentioned another question here: [Why Author Information isn't showing for all pages in google search result?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43041/why-author-information-isnt-showing-for-all-pages-in-google-search-result)

I am just suspecting may be this is the cause. Please let me know if you have a good solution for that question as well.

Try to see in google search result and it is not showing the rich snippet, where in the test tool it shows ok, just the error I attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my guess about why Google is offering to display your name as "Ali Rana" instead of "Md Ali Ahsan Rana".     "MD" is a common suffix used by doctors.  They assume that it isn't part of your legal name, but rather your professional title.  That leaves them with "Ali Ahsan Rana" and they take out the "middle" name leaving "Ali Rana".

Neither of those two rules sound like they are culturally appropriate for you, but these Google algorithms were likely written by engineers in the United States.  It would probably be best to raise this issue in the [Google Search Product Forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/websearch) so that somebody from Google can find out about the issue.

Comment: I have posted it on google product forum here: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/webmasters/c5swMi5MyFY . DO you think it is in right place? Because, I didn't get any reply yet and '5 views' only :(

Comment: I ended up knowing that google knows about this issue of multi word naming and is looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be caused by not full confirmation of your site in Google+. On Google Plus, fill the "Contributor to" field with the link to your site. Also you should left the link from your website to your G+ account (e.g. `https://plus.google.com/u/0/xxxxx121377144232527?rel=author`, where xxxxx121377144232527 is your G+ personal ID).

Regarding rich snippet in SERP you should wait as Google must reindex it.

Comment: Hi Marian, Thanks for your tips, I have already done this and it its properly set up currently. If google show the rich snippet after re-index, that's ok for me. But, I still want to remove the error I am having in verifying authorship, just in case.

Comment: Google plus has been retired and the suggestions in this answer are out of date.